# print html file using .vbs file

Tags: html, vba, printing

I am trying to print an html file using vb script.

File loaction is `D:\VbFiles\Test.html`

```
 Set WebBrowser1 = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

 WebBrowser1.Navigate "D:\VbFiles\Test.html"
 WebBrowser1.Visible = 1
```

I created `test.vbs` file with the above code and when I double click the file, im able to open IE with the specified html file, but not sure how to use print method here.

Please suggest

Thanks in Advance
Sandy

Comment: what do you mean by print method , what do you wanna print ?

Comment: I'm trying to print the html page

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution here:[Source](http://www.aspfree.com/c/a/Windows-Scripting/Printing-Documents-in-WSH/)

I am putting below what you need from the above link.

```
Const OLECMDID_PRINT = 6

Const OLECMDEXECOPT_DONTPROMPTUSER = 2

Const PRINT_WAITFORCOMPLETION = 2

Const OLECMDF_SUPPORTED = 1

Const OLECMDF_ENABLED = 2

blnPrintingComplete = False

Set objIE = WScript.CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application", "IE_")

objIE.Visible = False

objIE.Navigate "C:\Users\Me\Desktop\test.html"


Do While objIE.ReadyState <> 4

   WScript.Sleep 10

Loop

If objIE.QueryStatusWB(OLECMDID_PRINT) = OLECMDF_SUPPORTED + OLECMDF_ENABLED Then

   objIE.ExecWB OLECMDID_PRINT, OLECMDEXECOPT_DONTPROMPTUSER,PRINT_WAITFORCOMPLETION, 0

   Do While Not blnPrintingComplete

       WScript.Sleep 50

   Loop

End If


objIE.Quit
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for giving the sample code. But, it is giving `The object invoked has disconnected from its clients` error when used your code at line 20 - `Do While objIE.ReadyState <> 4`

Comment: Just add  `WScript.Sleep 1000` instead of the Do while loop in line 20 and check.

Comment: Commented do while loop and added just `WScript.Sleep 1000`. but now `Interface is unknown` error message coming at line 26 - `If objIE.QueryStatusWB(OLECMDID_PRINT) = OLECMDF_SUPPORTED + OLECMDF_ENABLED Then`